# How to create many instances with same attributes in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

How to detect which image is clicked , or how to add them IDs , is there any example where I could look , I searched with no luck.

```
import pygame , random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),16)
screen.fill((60,120,160))

instances = 10

while instances > 0:
    image = pygame.image.load("image.png").convert()
    image_rect = image.get_rect()
    image_rect[0] = random.randint(10,700)
    image_rect[1] = random.randint(10,500)
    screen.blit(image,image_rect)
    instances -= 1

pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                if image_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    print "image 1 clicked"
```

Comment: Use a list. If you loop it like that, it would get overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
instances = []

for _ in range(10):
    image = pygame.image.load("image.png").convert()
    image_rect = image.get_rect()
    image_rect.x = random.randint(10,700)
    image_rect.y = random.randint(10,500)
    screen.blit(image, image_rect)
    instances.append( (image, image_rect) )
```

Now you have all images on list `instances`
and you can get image by `instances[number]`

```
    if event.button == 1:
        for index, (image, image_rect) in enumerate(instances):
            if image_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print "image", index, "clicked"
```

--

BTW: your next step is to learn and use `class` and `Sprite`.